# User is getting task approval mails , even though the workflow has been terminated

Tags: workflow, content-approval, approval

We have a SharePoint 2010 **production** site in which number of documents are uploaded by different users having different custom permissions like author , approver , Admin . Usually Users with author permissions uploads a document to the library and creates an approval workflow on the uploaded document . Approval mail will be send to approver permission people and the process continues .

Last week we were facing some issues regarding those workflows so we cloned the production site on **per-production environment** .

Some of the authors terminated the workflows on **production site** but approvers are still getting workflow approval mails .
Is there any chances that the approvers are getting the mails due to same  workflows running on the **per-production** site which are not terminated ?

Comment: You have two environments Production and Pre-Production, As considered this condition.
You can check the the email body have the link to the document so you can find the email received from which Environment.
If the same users and workflow are avilable on the both the environment and you added the documents to both the sites then it's possible to receive email from anyone environment.

Comment: Is this workflow is also the OOTB? Not an Designer workflow am I right?

Comment: Yess . Workflow is OOTB